# PostgreSQL function return type record showing error

Tags: function, record, postgresql-9.1

I have below table and function.function created successfully but when i call the
function,it is showing error.

```
create table emp_details(empno int,ename varchar(20),sal numeric(7,2))

insert into emp_details values(101,'John',4500)
insert into emp_details values(101,'david',5000)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_select(IN eno integer)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS                                                                                   
$body$
BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY                                                       
        SELECT ename,sal FROM EMP_DETAILS WHERE EMPNO=eno;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

function created successfully.But while calling the function.it is showing error.how can we achieve in record type?

```
select test_select(101)
```

Comment: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `returns table` instead, that way you don't need to specify the column names when using the function. And you don't need PL/pgSQL for this, a `language sql` function is much more efficient if you just want to wrap a query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_select(IN eno integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (ename text, sal numeric)
AS                                                                                   
$body$
  SELECT ename,sal 
  FROM emp_details
  WHERE EMPNO=eno;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Set returning functions (regardless if defined as `returns setof` or with `returns table`) need to be used in the FROM clause, so you need to use it like this:

```sql
select *
from test_select(101);
```

Comment: Thank you.Suppose if i use setof Record as return type,i have to use out parameter in my function am i correct?